# Not able to acquire sessionid using urllib for screener.in

Tags: python, session-cookies, urllib, http-redirect

I am newbie to Python. I am trying to write a script in Python3.6 that will search for some values of stocks on screener.in site, for example PEG ratio.

The problem is I can get the PEG ratio only after login to the screener.in. my python script login to the screener but after login to the screener the CookieJar should contain csrftoken and sessionid but instead the CookieJar only contains csrftoken. After login to screener.in the site redirects to page https://www.screener.in/dash/. During this redirection in HTTPRedirectHandler I can see there is sessionid present in hds parameter. But how to add it to CookieJar and even though if I add it as below

c = http.cookiejar.Cookie(version=0, name="sessionid", value=val, port=None, port_specified=False, domain="www.screener.in", domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, 
                                      secure=True, expires='1552204782', discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest=None)
self.jar.set_cookie(c)

CookieJar get reset during call to get PEG Ration for a company(in script I am trying to get ratio for bharat rasayan(https://www.screener.in/company/BHARATRAS/). Below is my script

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import http.cookiejar
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import timegm




class HTTPRedirectHandler(urllib.request.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def __init__(self, jar):
        self.jar = jar

    def redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, hds, newurl):

        sessionid = ''
        for i in hds._headers:
            if i[0] != 'Set-Cookie':
                continue
            if i[1].startswith('sessionid='):
                sessionid = i[1]
                print("In redirect_request(): SessionId found value is: " + sessionid + "\n\n")
                break

        newreq = super().redirect_request(
            req, fp, code, msg, hds, newurl)


        return newreq



def get_url(url, data=None, timeout=30, opener=None, requestHeader = None, jar = None):
  '''get_url accepts a URL string and return the server response code, response headers, and contents of the file'''

  req_headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36'
  }

  if requestHeader:
      req_headers.update(requestHeader)

  request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=req_headers, data=data)
  if not opener:
    jar = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    redirectHandler = HTTPRedirectHandler(jar)


    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar), redirectHandler)


  while 1:
    try:
        response = opener.open(request)
    except Exception as inst:
        print(type(inst))
        print(inst.args)
        print(inst)

    break

  jar.extract_cookies(response, request)
  print("In get_url(): ")
  print(jar.make_cookies(response, request))

  code = response.code
  headers = response.headers
  html = response.read()
  return code, headers, html, opener, jar



code, headers, html, cur_opener, jar = get_url('https://www.screener.in/login/', timeout=3)

#responceHeaders = headers['Set-Cookie']
#responceHeaders = responceHeaders[responceHeaders.find('=') + 1:responceHeaders.find(';')]
#print(responceHeaders)
#print(headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
fdata = soup.find_all('input', {'name': "csrfmiddlewaretoken"})
csrfMiddlewareToken = str(fdata[0])
csrfMiddlewareToken = csrfMiddlewareToken[csrfMiddlewareToken.find('value="') + len('value="') : csrfMiddlewareToken.find('>') -1]
print("The value of csrfMiddlewareToken is: " + csrfMiddlewareToken + "\n\n")
requestHeaderL ={ 'referer' : 'https://www.screener.in/login/', 'origin' : 'https://www.screener.in', 'Connection' : "keep-alive", 'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate', 'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin', 'sec-fetch-user': '?1'}

login_data = urllib.parse.urlencode({ 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrfMiddlewareToken, 'next': '', 'username' : "screenerintest@gmail.com", 'password' : "91@Screener", 'action' : 'login'}).encode('UTF-8') 
code, headers, html, cur_opener, jar = get_url('https://www.screener.in/login/', data=login_data, timeout=3, opener= cur_opener, requestHeader=requestHeaderL, jar=jar)
print("The value of respond headers is: ")
print(headers)

code, headers, html, cur_opener, jar = get_url('https://www.screener.in/company/BHARATRAS/',timeout=3, opener= cur_opener, requestHeader=requestHeaderL, jar= jar)
soup= BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
fdata = soup.find_all('li')


for i in fdata:
    strVal = i.get_text().replace('\n','').strip()
    val = strVal[0:strVal.find(':')].strip()
    if val != 'PEG Ratio':
        continue
    else:
        print('\nPEG Ratio found\n')
        break;
else:
    print('\nPEG Ratio not found')
```

Values returned by screener.in for bharat rasayan before login

Market Cap:  2,031 Cr. Current Price:  4,778 52 weeks High / Low  7939.95 / 3325.00 Book Value:  961.91 Stock P/E: 15.61 Dividend Yield: 0.03 % ROCE: 39.06 % ROE: 38.86 % Sales Growth (3Yrs): 21.87 % Listed on BSE and NSE Company Website Face Value:  10.00

and after login

Market Cap:  2,031 Cr. Current Price:  4,778 52 weeks High / Low  7939.95 / 3325.00 Book Value:  961.91 Stock P/E: 15.61 Dividend Yield: 0.03 % ROCE: 39.06 % ROE: 38.86 % Sales Growth (3Yrs): 21.87 % Listed on BSE and NSE Company Website Face Value:  10.00
PEG Ratio: 0.27

Note: PEG Ratio is shown after login.

Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Actually I need to save the sessionid and pass it as header. 
Also, I was not getting PEG ratio as for that I need to make a API call to api/company/758/quick_ratios/

Thanks.